# How to access the context of a unknown parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context, use-context

Suppose, I have two separate components X and Y, where X is a dependency in Y(not a direct child in the project). Is it possible to access the context of Y in X?

ex:

```
<Y.Provider value={key: 'val'}>
   <X />
</Y.Provider>
```

X is a separate project want to access Y's context, how can it be done?
Can I import the context of Y in X and use it? Y is totally a separate(unknown until X is used as a dependency in Y) component?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access some parent variable, the parent has to pass it as a prop.

Y could pass the props needed to its children

```
const Y = (props) => {
   const myVariable = 1

   return React.cloneElement(props.children, { context: myVariable })
}
```

Then X could access it via `props.context.myVariable`